# How to get the tuple form out of the one line input?

Tags: c, split

I got a code below.
If the user input `(12,34,56,78),(1,2,3)`,
it will only output: `12,34,56,78,1,2,3`
but I need to output `(12,34,56,78) (1,2,3)`
what should I do?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char enter[100];
    int a;

    printf("Enter a string:");    
    scanf("%s",enter);
    char *tuples=strtok(enter,"()");
    while(tuples!=NULL){
        printf("%s",tuples);
        tuples=strtok(NULL,"()");
    }

}
```

Comment: `(  ... )` is extracted and processed each it.

Comment: `strchr()` may help you., Or, if you prefer `strtok()`, parst, then post format to re-insert the characters you need.

Comment: Try `while(tuples!=NULL){
        printf("(%s)", tuples);
        tuples=strtok(NULL,"()"); putchar(tuples ? ' ' : '\n');
    }`

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/H8Tt7U)

Comment: `printf("%s",tuples);` --> `if(strcmp(tuples, ",")==0)
      putchar(' ');
     else
         printf("(%s)",tuples);`

Comment: @chux-- ^^^ this will also print the comma separating the tuples in parentheses....

Comment: @chux Your approach needs one more `strtok`. (And for `break` in the case of `NULL`, I think it is necessary to replace `?:;` with `if`.)

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes there is a pesky `,` that needs attention.  Hmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[strchr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm)*  is an additional parsing tool that may help you. It provides a method to quickly locate a specific character within a string, and return a pointer to that location.  This capability, along with *[sprintf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)* can be used to reconstruct the string without the middle ",".  Following is an illustration.

```
int main(void)
{
    char string[40] = {"(12,34,56,78),(1,2,3)"};
    char *ret;
    int len1,len2;
    char *first = strdup(string);//a 2nd copy is needed to preserve the 1st half of string.
    char last[20];

    len1 = strlen(string);

    //in your example, the ')' character is the closest unique char to the 
    //target ',', so select this unique character to get close...
    ret = strchr(string, ')');//brings pointer to first ')'
    ret += 2; //increment pointer past next occurring "," to get second half of string
    strcpy(last, ret);

    len2 = strlen(last);
    first[len1-(len2+1)] = 0;//use length information to get first half

    sprintf(string, "%s %s", first, last); 
    printf(string);                 
    free(first);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

> (12,34,56,78) (1,2,3)

A note on user input:
It occurred to me that legal syntax (you have stated no rules) for this seemingly simple scenario can easily result in variations that will make a general solution for parsing and string re-construction difficult.  eg, input could be any of the following:

```
(12,34,56,78),(1,2,3)  
( 12 , 34 , 56 , 78 ) , ( 1 , 2 , 3 )  
(12,34,56,78)      ,       (1,2,3)  
(and many more)
```

Keep in mind, to build a general approach to handling user input, the complexity of the code needed to process the input will be inversely proportional to the bounds (rules) put on input. i.e. if there are zero rules, the complexity will be infinite. If there are many rules governing allowed input, the complexity of the code will be proportionally smaller.

A good example of unbounded input is the way people talk.  There is very little convention followed in the way people choose to convey their thoughts. (*[natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language)* is similar in it variations to user input)  A few examples illustrating the complexity needed to process natural language *[are listed here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=natural+language+processing+in+C&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5ptLkz-3VAhXCqlQKHWqNBVsQgQMIQTAA)*.

(The input rules in your post are not clearly stated, so any attempt at a trivial solution here, will not likely satisfy any but those with input having syntax similar to your example)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions quote: "It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample"

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset - Lol, Thank you for pointing this out.  I don't usually, but in this case, a compilable illustration was the best way to convey my thoughts.  Besides, you were pretty selective in choosing only the part of the quoted sentence that supports your view.   The rest of it: (for posterity): _...if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment._.  In this case, I believe it helps the student.

Comment: Yes sorry for the cherry picking :) I think your example is good in that it shows a minimal viable solution, that can be improved upon a lot etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use more advanced parsing than `strtok`. `strtok`, as you learn if you read the manual page ([`man strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)), will return the strings between each occurance of one of the delimiter characters, which for you is `"()"`.

To achieve the result you want, you need code that:

1. Finds the opening parenthesis
2. Collects all numbers until a closing parenthesis
3. repeat from 1

This parsing can be done with calls to `strtok`, `strstr`, other string functions, or manually by parsing the string char for char.

When you have your list of touple contents you can print them surrounded by parentheses (without comma in between if you so desire).

Answer (score 0):

If the input format is constrained to two tuples, as in the example, then you can use a simple `sscanf()` construction to parse this. Note that in the solutions below, valid input consists of possible leading whitespace, followed by a `(` character, followed by a non-empty string, followed by a `)` character, possibly followed by more whitespace or a comma. Further input validation would be needed to verify that the strings between parentheses are indeed tuples.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[] = "(12, 34, 56, 78),(1, 2, 3)";

    char tuple1[100];
    char tuple2[100];

    if (sscanf(input, " (%[^)]) , (%[^)]", tuple1, tuple2) == 2) {
        printf("(%s) (%s)\n", tuple1, tuple2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
(12, 34, 56, 78) (1, 2, 3)
```

But, if the number of input tuples is unknown (a large number of tuples must not be expected, since `enter` has been declared `char enter[100]` in the example code), this method can be extended by using the `%n` `scanf()` directive. This directive stores the number of characters read thus far in its argument. A pointer to the next segment of the input string to be read can be formed by adding this offset value to a pointer to the initial input string.

The program below expects the tuples to be separated by commas, and will simply stop parsing if two tuples occur without a comma between them, or otherwise malformed input is encountered. Some care is required to handle this case, since the assignment to `offset` is not made if the final comma of the format string is not matched. Here, `offset` is initialized to zero, and reset to zero at the end of each loop iteration. Before the reset, if `offset` is already zero, then no assignment was made, meaning that the final comma was not matched (signalling the end of input), and the loop is exited.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[] = "(12, 34, 56, 78),(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7)";

    char tuple[100];
    char *next = input;
    int offset = 0;
    int ret_val = 0;

    do {
        ret_val = sscanf(next, " (%[^)]) ,%n", tuple, &offset);
        if (ret_val == 1) {
            printf("(%s) ", tuple);
            next += offset;
        }

        if (offset) {
            offset = 0;
        } else {
            break;
        }

    } while (ret_val == 1);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
(12, 34, 56, 78) (1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY-- I don't think so, in that case `offset` has been set to zero already....

Comment: sorry, I got it early. You already have notes and countermeasures.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY-- that falls under the "some care required" part of the answer; this is one downside of using `sscanf()` for such tasks.... I didn't realize until just now that you had linked to a similar solution [in the comments under the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839889/how-to-get-the-tuple-form-out-of-the-one-line-input/45841756#comment78638403_45839889)

Answer (score 0):

if tuples do not contain subtuples:

```
void printTuples(char *s)
{
    char *str;
    char *tmps = s;
    int flag = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        str = strtok(tmps, "()");
        tmps = NULL;
        if (str == NULL) break;
        if((flag = !flag)) printf("( %s )", str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle input such as `(12,34,56,78)(1,2,3)` too gracefully, and treats `(12,34,56,78),(1,2,3)` and `)12,34,56,78(,)1,2,3(` as identical input

Comment: @David Bowling Of course. Any simple solution will fail on some inputs - your as well -  "(12, 34, 56, 79),(),(5, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7)"; only proper parser will able to tokenize it but it is not the scope of the question

Comment: My version stops parsing when malformed input is encountered. The resulting output of my code from your example would be `(12, 34, 6, 79)`. Of course, I am assuming that an empty tuple is malformed input; OP has not stipulated this....

Comment: I am going to argue - 3 lines parser will never work. And his question as I understand it is not about it. He just did not know how to avoid the "middle" token in his strtok call and I just shown him how. I **agree** that is not the proper tokenizer and it never was claimed as one.

Comment: Fair enough; OP solution was bound to have these difficulties anyway....